# how to define a button when we have another function in that?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am beginner in tkinter. I have a code that works well. it reads a textfile and processes on that and writes it as new text file. Then, it opens it again and makes it to a list of numbers.

```
import string

def expand(chunk):
    l = chunk.split("*")
    chunk = [str(float(l[1]))] * int(l[0])
    return chunk

with open('test.txt', 'r') as infile1, open('target1.txt', 'w') as outfile1:
    for line in infile1:
        if set(string.ascii_letters.replace("e","")) & set(line):
            continue

        chunks = line.split(" ")
        #Get rid of newlines
        chunks = list(map(lambda chunk: chunk.strip(), chunks))
        if "/" in chunks:
            chunks.remove("/")

        new_chunks = []
        for i in range(len(chunks)):
            if '*' in chunks[i]:
                new_chunks += expand(chunks[i])
            else:
                new_chunks.append(chunks[i])
        new_chunks[len(new_chunks)-1] = new_chunks[len(new_chunks)-1]+"\n"
        new_line = " ".join(new_chunks)
        outfile1.write(new_line)

f = open('target1.txt').read()
A = f.split()
B = list(map(float, A))
print(B)
```

I want to bring it in tkinter, and define a openfile widget and a button to process the same thing. I wrote this code below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import string

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

def expand(chunk):
    l = chunk.split("*")
    chunk = [str(float(l[1]))] * int(l[0])

def opentext():
    my_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir ="/pycharm", title ="Select your file",\
                                               filetype=(("text file", "*.txt"),("all files","*.*"))) 
    with open(my_file, 'r') as infile1, open('target1.txt', 'w') as outfile1:
        for line in infile1:
            if set(string.ascii_letters.replace("e", "")) & set(line):
                continue

            chunks = line.split(" ")
            # Get rid of newlines
            chunks = list(map(lambda chunk: chunk.strip(), chunks))
            if "/" in chunks:
                chunks.remove("/")

            new_chunks = []
            for i in range(len(chunks)):
                if '*' in chunks[i]:
                    new_chunks += expand(chunks[i])
                else:
                    new_chunks.append(chunks[i])
            new_chunks[len(new_chunks) - 1] = new_chunks[len(new_chunks) - 1] + "\n"
            new_line = " ".join(new_chunks)
            outfile1.write(new_line)

    f = open('target1.txt').read()
    A = f.split()
    B = list(map(float, A))

    my_label = Label(text=A).pack()

my_button = Button(root, text = "Open a file", command=opentext).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

it gives me this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pymnb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\pymnb\Desktop\pycharm\open a file.py", line 29, in opentext
    new_chunks += expand(chunks[i])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I dont understand which part I am making a mistake. Is that because I have a function inside another function?

Comment: You're creating the button fine. The problem isn't with the button, it's with the code called by the button. You're assuming some variables have values when they are `None`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the code works well standalone

Comment: Your problem is that your `expand` function does not return anything.  I suspect you wanted `return` instead of `chunk =`.

Comment: amazing. it worked. Could you please wite your answer that I can select it as best answer. thank you very much